# Failed to install Potree on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: installation, lidar, ubuntu, lastools, potree

I am trying to install Potree on my computer and I am stuck. I am following these instructions:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties git
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake g++
$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
$ sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
$ sudo apt-get install gcc
```

LAStools:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/m-schuetz/LAStools.git
$ cd LAStools/LASzip
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
$ make
```

Potree Converter:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/potree/PotreeConverter.git
$ cd PotreeConverter
$ mkdir build && cd build  
**$ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLASZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/ubuntu/LAStools/LASzip/dll -DLASZIP_LIBRARY=/home/ubuntu/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so ..**
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ln -s ~/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so /usr/lib
$ PotreeConverter -h
```

Anyway, I installed LAStools and I have problem with Potree. When I run command:

`sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLASZIP_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/ubuntu/LAStools/LASzip/dll -DLASZIP_LIBRARY=/home/ubuntu/LAStools/LASzip/build/src/liblaszip.so ..`

I get:

```
-- Build type is 'Release'
-- Compiler is not EMSCRIPTEN
CMake Warning at Converter/libs/brotli/CMakeLists.txt:319 (message):
  Test file tests/testdata/alice29.txt does not exist.


CMake Warning at Converter/libs/brotli/CMakeLists.txt:319 (message):
  Test file tests/testdata/asyoulik.txt does not exist.


CMake Warning at Converter/libs/brotli/CMakeLists.txt:319 (message):
  Test file tests/testdata/lcet10.txt does not exist.


CMake Warning at Converter/libs/brotli/CMakeLists.txt:319 (message):
  Test file tests/testdata/plrabn12.txt does not exist.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTBB.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "TBB", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "TBB" with any of
  the following names:

    TBBConfig.cmake
    tbb-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "TBB" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "TBB_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "TBB" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/PotreeConverter/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/PotreeConverter/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing tbb.
This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt update ; sudo apt install libtbb-dev
```